# To display div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had 10 div with name `sample`

```
<div name="sample">div1</div>
<div name="sample">div2</div>
<div name="sample">div3</div>
<div name="sample">div4</div>
<div name="sample">div5</div>
<div name="sample">div6</div>
<div name="sample">div7</div>
<div name="sample">div8</div>
<div name="sample">div9</div>
<div name="sample">div10</div>
<input type="button" id="display" value="display">
```

once display button in clicked i need to display two div

**first click**: display div1 and div2 [other div are none]

**second click**: display div3 and div4 [other div are none]

etc...

How to do this with jquery

Comment: I dont know how to do this in cyclic way @anand

Comment: what do you mean by "cyclic"???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#display').bind('click', function() {
   var $divs   = $('div'),
       offset  = 0;

   return function() {
       $divs.hide().slice(offset, offset+2).show();
       offset += 2;

       if( offset === 10 )
           offset = 0;
   };
}()).click();
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yNABj/3/

Comment: looks like you forgot to immedialetly invoke your [immediately invoked function](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) ? :-) (the one passed to bind())

Comment: Brrr.. had a annoying hard time to figure that out, lol. time to go home.

Answer (score 2):

With this script, each time the button is clicked, 2 divs are shown and the others are hidden:

```
$('#display').click((function() {
    var divs = $('div[name="sample"]');
    var offset = 0;
    return function() {
        if (offset >= divs.length) offset = 0;
        divs.hide().slice(offset, offset+2).show();
        offset += 2;
    };
})());
```

Each time the button is clicked, the two next divs are shown, and the others are hidden. And it restarts once all divs have been shown.

(This has been partially inspired by [jAndy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795199/to-display-div-dynamically/4795283#4795283) while he deleted his answer)

Comment: after displaying div9 and div10. i again need to start from div1 and div2. How to do this is my question

Comment: `slice(2)` should be `slice(0,2)`.

Comment: i need to display only 2 div in a click but each time while i click two div getting display. i need to hide prev opened div

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('div[name=sample]:nth-child(1)').show();
$('div[name=sample]:nth-child(3)').show();
```

then

```
$('div[name=sample]:nth-child(2)').show();
$('div[name=sample]:nth-child(4)').show();
```